# Node Js Express create background job

Tags: node.js, express, cron, job-scheduling, background-task

is there any best practice to create background job in server node js with express?
I need create job to generate code for >= 1m customer then send sms and email to them all,
Operator only trigger the job with click "start job" button. I'm using mysql database.

and how to make process not included in server thread, that mean if server done the job still running.

[search with google get this : sample using express & mongoDb](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2015/07/23/running-background-jobs-with-express/)

Comment: can you provide some of your code please?

Comment: I'm still not code for the background process, I'm still looking for best practice